# Phonegap ios pushnotification

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

I am new to `iOS` programming don't know anything about objective-c . I have done `Push Notification` on `Android` and it is working properly.I am using `Cordova` to implement in cross-platform device so, anybody can help me out how can I implement it in `iOS` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working on `cordova` then you can implement push notification using plugins available in `cordova`. You can use **`PushPlugin`** in you app, it will work for both `Android` as well as `iOS`. For more information about `pushPlugin` please [Click Here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin).

You have to follow some steps for `iOS` to implement push notification. For more description please visit link mentioned [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/).

While generating `.pem` certificate for **iOS** please execute command written below instead of command written at point 10.

> cat apns-dev-cert.pem apns-dev-key-noenc.pem > apns-dev.pem

You can also refer link mentioned here http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1